# NSLog "const float *"

Tags: objective-c

Quick question: How can I debug values in a constant with type `const float *` in Objective-C ?

The object is declared as follow in an `.h` file:

```
const float *vertices;
```

Tried `%d` (integer) , `%@` , `%f` (double), but warnings prompted:

```
%@ , Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'const float *'
%d , Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'const float *'
%f , Format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'const float *'
```

Comment: What is your warning?

Comment: Added warning in question

Comment: You seems to confuse pointer and value, please add also the NSLog ligne.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by debug you mean you want to print its value?

```
NSLog(@"%p: %f", vertices, * vertices);
```

this will print its address and float value in the address

as @KenThomases suggested, you may need to check `vertices` is not `NULL` if you can't guarantee it.  and to print out all values in `vertices`:

```
NSUInteger length = // length of vertices

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%f", vertices[i]);
}
```

Comment: Correct with caveats: 1) if `vertices` is `NULL`, dereferencing it will crash. 2) since `vertices` is plural, it's most likely a pointer to an array. Your suggestion would only log the first element. You could log more elements using `vertices[1]`, etc. You'd need to know how many elements there were. There's no way for the compiler nor `NSLog()` to figure that out from a plain pointer.